# saber cantidad de post que estan en otra tabla, de cada uno de los usuarios

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito ayuda:

tengo una **tabla_usuario** con los items (id, nombre) 
 y una **tabla_post** (id, user_id, etc... )

necesito que cuando liste la tabla_usuarios, me diga cuantos post tiene cada uno de los usuarios en otra columna algo asi

```
id, nombre, cantidadPost
========================
1 | carlos | 0
2 | manuel | 2
3 | sofia  | 5
```

Comment: [Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

podria realizar una subConsulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select
tabla_usuario.id, tabla_usuario.nombre,
( 
 select count(id) from tabla_post where tabla_post.user_id=tabla_usuario.id
) AS total_posts
from tabla_usuario
```

saludos